# Use parentheses to enclose a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have accidentally discovered the Ruby idiom of `||=()`,
as in:

```
def app_logger
  @app_logger ||= (
    logfile = File.open(::Rails.root.join(LOG_FILE), 'a')
    logfile.sync = true
    AppLogger.new(logfile)
  )
end
```

I tried to use `{}` instead of `()`, but it didn't work.  I thought `{}` is meant to enclose a block.

Is this a known idiom?  Is it a good style?

I haven't found much documentation on this kind of use of parentheses.  Any pointers would be helpful.

Please note this post is about the use of `()` this way, not the use of `||=`. There are many posts about this latter idiom already.

Comment: This is where you want `begin`: `@app_logger ||= begin ... end`

Comment: `@app_logger ||= {}` says to make `@app_logger` an empty hash if it does not have a value already

Comment: () seems to be functionally equivalent to begin, end in this case. It's shorter, plus if it's on one line,   foo ||= (a=10; a+10) is much nicer than  foo ||= begin a=10; a+10 end

Comment: You are using parenthesis to raise the order of operations of the enclosed lines so they get evaluated as a group, and the final value gets returned. It's not a block or a substitute for one, it just tells Ruby to "do this first".

Comment: In the code in my original post, if @app_logger is already defined, then the stuff within the parenthesis is not executed, which is my intention.  Would you agree that the () and begin-end are functionally identical, only stylistically different?

Comment: No, they're not functionally identical. For your example there is a side-effect to using parenthesis that results in the same answer, but you can't substitute parenthesis for a block in other situations where blocks are used. Relying on side-effects in a language is a bug in waiting.

Comment: Your point well taken. I'm not claiming using () and begin-end are functionally equivalent in ALL cases.  But in my example, they seem to be.  Actually I was surprised that it worked, hence my original post.

Answer (score 6):

Like a lot of things in Ruby that *can* be done, many of them *shouldn't* be done and this is one of them.

Using brackets to group code when there are already other facilities is potentially confusing and almost certainly contrary to many coding style guides. If I saw this in code I was managing, I'd immediately fix it.

What's best is to use the `begin`/`end` markers to make it completely clear what's going on:

```
def app_logger
  @app_logger ||= begin
    logfile = File.open(::Rails.root.join(LOG_FILE), 'a')
    logfile.sync = true
    AppLogger.new(logfile)
  end
end
```

A lot of things in Ruby evaluate down to a single value, and the contents of `(...)` are apparently one of those things.

Your other example of `foo ||= (a=10; a+10)` being "nicer" is also rather controversial. This does two assignment and addition, but only conditionally. This one would almost always be better written in long-form with `begin`/`end` to make it clear that `a+10` is the result.

From a style perspective, hiding the "important" part of that, the `a+10`, at the end of a line is bad, it can be overlooked. Having it as the last line makes it abundantly clear. This is also why having `if` statements tacked on the end of long lines is also bad, it hides that the line is only conditionally executed.

Concern for brevity is always trumped by concerns of readability. Saving a couple of bytes on disk is not going to help you one bit when, due to someone misreading your code, they introduce a crippling bug.

That *someone* could be you in the future when you get caught up in your own cleverness. It's happened to all of us at some point.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comments.  In this case, I still think () is more clear, more succinct, easier on the eye, and without introducing any ambiguity or confusion.  The only potential issue is that if this is an undocumented feature of Ruby and it won't be supported in the future.

Comment: I come from the Perl world, where the use of idiom adds to the expressiveness of the language;  there're often several ways of writing the same logic.  One can argue the use of idiom can be confusing especially for the uninitiated.  But by mastering the idiom, one can write more elegant, more succinct code.  Less code (which is one of Ruby's core philosophies) is code more maintainable.

Comment: But I do agree with you on the importance of clarity of code as well.  So if an idiom (not in this case, in my opinion) makes the code harder to understand, then perhaps it's better not to use it.

Comment: +1 "Concern for brevity is always trumped by concerns of readability." And, "That someone could be you in the future when you get caught up in your own cleverness. It's happened to all of us at some point."... Nuh-uh. Not me. Never. :-)

Comment: @ZackXu, " Less code (which is one of Ruby's core philosophies) is code more maintainable." I wrote in Perl starting with v2, and continue to support Perl code, and, along with many others, would counter that one of Perl's great failings is its code is often reduced to little more than line-noise. It's easy to write terse/succinct code once you understand how a language works, especially if you started with assembler or C. Writing fast, clean and clear code that is maintainable is a more worthy goal.

Comment: As a veteran with many years of Perl experience, once you start thinking in Perl that line noise turns into a form of beautiful simplicity, however what you often forget is it's still line-noise to those who aren't in that mind-set. It's similar to teenagers and their impenetrable TXT SPK (e.g. KTHXBAI) that looks like something that would require a cryptoanalyst to decipher. Like many, I thought Perl Golf was a great way to learn about obscure features of the language, but really the lesson was that tight, terse, jewel-like code is not at all friendly to others.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @tadman's answer, I'd counter that writing the method in a more Ruby-like way maintains the readability and keeps it nice and tight:

```
def app_logger
  return @app_logger if @app_logger

  logfile = File.open(::Rails.root.join(LOG_FILE), 'a')
  logfile.sync = true
  @app_logger = AppLogger.new(logfile)
end
```

---

For my intent and rationale in writing it this way, see my comment to this answer in response to @fotanus's comment.

Our brains become conditioned to see patterns as we learn to program and learn new languages. Whether the patterns are in hexcode emitted by a debugger or C, Perl, Python, Java or Ruby, we still see patterns. When we're used to seeing them we tend to want to change code to resemble those familiar constructs. That's why Perl and C programmers tend to write Java, Python and Ruby like C and Perl at first. The "beauty is in the eye of the beholder", but that same beauty is a weed when it's out of place, just as wild-flowers are out of place in formal gardens or the middle of a fairway. We should write in the vernacular of the programming language, because that is the way of speaking expected by those who live in that land.

Something to remember is, though we, personally, might be a code-studly monster who can reduce code from multiple lines down to a single character, what will keep me in a job is the ability to write code *other* people can understand, without necessarily having to be of the same caliber. Code crunching invariably reaches a point of diminishing returns, well before it has been reduced to its minimal size, especially when that code is running in a production environment and is being maintained by junior programmers and there is a need to extend or debug it, and the clock is ticking. `Minutes = dollars` where I work, and the dollars have really big multipliers, which causes the walls to leak managers like cockroaches when a bug-bomb goes off. (Oh... did I call managers cockroaches? Whatever.)

Being called the morning after an event and being thanked for writing code that made it easy for them to debug/fix or amend/extend is a whole lot better than being called at 2:45AM and asked to get online to help. I value my sleep and that of my coding-partners and push for maintainable code as our #1 priority.

That's my $0.02.

Comment: I also thought in write a ansewer just like this, but after write it and look at it I really thing the _ruby way_ is the one proposed by @tadman

Comment: I think @tadman's answer is rewriting the OPs code in a more Ruby-like way, showing how to do it correctly *IF* that idiom was to be used. I seldom see Ruby code written that way. Instead, I've seen a lot more written as I did, not relying on `||=` at all. `||=` is very powerful and is a nice short-hand, but it's also an operator that confuses programmers over and over. Stack Overflow is full of questions about its meaning and use. I doubt there are 1/10 the number of questions about a trailing `if`.

Comment: +1 for bring this. You might want to add something like this comment in our answer, to make it a better one

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are really ugly for in my opinion. Why you don't delegate logic behind creating logger to method?

```
def app_logger
  @app_logger ||= instantiate_app_logger
end

def instantiate_app_logger
  logfile = File.open(::Rails.root.join(LOG_FILE), 'a')
  logfile.sync = true
  AppLogger.new(logfile)
end
```

But I am afraid that it breaks some OOP, your code also. Why AppLoger class can't open file based on passed path and turning syncing on? It will be so much cleaner.